# One Root view controller , Manages all other views?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I was just wondering if its normal for an app to a have one root view controller which gets passed other view controllers and switches betwen them ? - in other words there is one view controller which switches between all other views.

So one root controller manages all the other views ( so in a large application for the sake of argument this could be like 15 views?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a common approach. Very handy also when it comes to transitions between the views.